# Highchart-ng not displaying inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I've got a directive that contains highchart-ng and I need to update the series data inside the directive from my Service to fetch the data.

I got it working without the service - basically this works https://jsfiddle.net/w657bcdp/

However, if I update the series inside my service, it doesn't work. The debugger shows the chart series data being loaded but does not display.

```
...
var defer = $q.defer();
defer.resolve(DashbboardSrv.loadStats());

defer.promise.then(function(resp){


    ...

    var data = [
                    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 18), 0   ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 26), 0.2 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11,  1), 0.47],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 11), 0.55],
                    [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.38],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  0,  8), 1.38],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  0, 15), 1.38],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  1), 1.38],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  1,  8), 1.48],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  1, 21), 1.5 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 12), 1.89],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  2, 25), 2.0 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  4), 1.94],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  3,  9), 1.91],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 13), 1.75],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  3, 19), 1.6 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 25), 0.6 ],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  4, 31), 0.35],
                    [Date.UTC(1971,  5,  7), 0   ]
                 ];


                scope.chartConfig.series = [{
                        type: 'area',
                        name : 'votes',
                        data: data,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueDecimals: 2
                        }
                      }]
}
, function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message);
})
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: How do you change the series?

Comment: @kabaehr - `scope.chartConfig.series = [...` just like the snippet in my code

Comment: Maybe a timeout like you did in the jsfiddle will work

Comment: didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I found the issue in my directive link function. I had wrapped the code above in a function within the link function itself and was causing issues in AngularJS probably.

The solution is to create the function with scope:

```
...
link: {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {                  

                scope.chartConfig = {...}

                scope.loadStats();     //loadStats() wont' work.


               scope.loadStats = function(){...}
       ...
      }
```